# Чтение файла json при помощи javascript и node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Задача состоит в том, чтобы прочитать json-файл, который уже есть на сайте, и распарсить его. Нужно распарсить файл data.json и вывести его данные на страницу (вывод уже знаю как реализовать).

Вот список всех файлов, которые есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал node.js json при помощи init, там отобразилась библиотека fs.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Применяю эту библиотеку fs в javascript:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const p_body_content = document.getElementById("p_body_content");
// read json file
const data = fs.readFileSync('./data.json', { encoding: "utf8" });
let dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(dataObj)
p_body_content.prepend(dataObj.header)
```

и оно выдаёт ошибку: `uncaught referenceerror require is not defined`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Node.js исполняется на сервере. На клиенте(браузере) работать не будет, это разное!

Comment: тогда при помощи чего мне читать json файл?

Comment: Допустим [fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch) - пусть вытягивает данные с сервера. Либо напрямую, обратившись к файлу, либо через api, поднятую на node.js

Comment: можешь пример какойто скинуть. н понимаю как при помощи fetch локально читать файл?

Comment: Что значит - локально? Браузер не позволит брать файлы с диска без разрешения пользователя. Можно дергать локальный сервер. А в целом, отредактируйте вопрос и дополните его, какую именно задачу вы решаете, какого поведения вы хотите достичь и какими средствами

Comment: отредактировал!

Comment: Как вы заходите на страничку? Просто открываете `html` файлик или переходите по ссылке аля `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: я открываю локальный сервер через liveserver

Comment: Тогда вы через [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) можете получить `json` файлик.

Comment: но я не могу понать как это сделать, если можете помочь написать этот код буду вам очень благодарен!

Comment: `fetch('путь_к_файлу').then(r => r.json()).then(data => /* ваш код обработки */)`